# Sequence or order of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I show the status (OK, NOT) based on the sequence of the products that came in to the shop, the condition is as follows:
    IF 4 or less BULBS before FRION Then Status will be OK
    IF 5 or more BULBS before FRION then Status will be NOT

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGHH2.png)

Comment: Look up gaps and islands. And show expected output.  Post text not an image.

Comment: Please post the expected result for each row, to understand more clearly.

Comment: I've added the expected results in the status column, thank you in advance.

Comment: You did not add it as text.

Comment: Does text means the query?  I am just starting to learn SQL and a bit slow when it comes to terminologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dran, I think the following should work for you in SQL Server 2008.

I've written it all off the top of my head without running or debugging it, so excuse any small errors (I always say this to cover myself), but I'm sure you can see the gist of the approach.

The first two steps are basically to segment products which are sequential in time, into contiguous blocks - subtracting one sequential row number from another gives a unique "segment number" (with an irregular stepping).

Once they're segmented, we count how many rows are in each. We also rank the segments themselves to establish the numbered order of each segment (and provide a sequential segment number, rather than irregularly-stepped, so that we can look back to the immediately-prior segment later by subtracting 1 from the current segment number).

And we number the rows within each segment, to ensure that the join later can target a single row within a segment (in order to check the count of that segment, and without a successful join causing the row on the left to be duplicated according to the number of rows on the right, as a join normally would).

```
WITH step1 AS
(
    SELECT
        product
        ,time
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) AS rownum_by_time
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time) AS rownum_prod_by_time
    FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
)
,step2 AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,(rownum_by_time - rownum_prod_by_time) AS prod_sgmt
    FROM step1
)
,step3 AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,MIN(time) OVER (PARTITION BY product, prod_sgmt) AS prod_sgmt_earliest_time
    FROM step2
)
,analysed_data AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,COUNT(ALL product) OVER (PARTITION BY product, prod_sgmt) AS prod_sgmt_count
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, prod_sgmt ORDER BY time) AS prod_sgmt_rownum
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY prod_sgmt_earliest_time) AS prod_sgmt_rank
    FROM step3
)
SELECT
    ad.product
    ,ad.time
    ,CASE 
        WHEN adsj.product IS NOT NULL THEN
            'NOT'
        ELSE
            'OK'
        END AS status --if we have a join that met the criteria, it's not ok, otherwise ok

FROM 
    analysed_data AS ad

LEFT JOIN
    analysed_data AS adsj --self join so we can get the prior segment
    ON (ad.product = 'Frion') --only consider joining if we're dealing with a row in a Frion segment
    AND (ad.prod_sgmt_rownum = 1) --only for the first row in the Frion segment
    AND (adsj.product = 'Bulbs') --only consider joining to Bulb segments
    AND (adsj.prod_sgmt_rank = (ad.prod_sgmt_rank - 1)) --and only if the Bulb segment is the immediately prior segment
    AND (adsj.prod_sgmt_rownum = 1) --only join to the first row in the Bulb segment (since they all carry the total row count for their segment)
    AND (adsj.prod_sgmt_count > 4) --only join if the Bulb segment contains more than 4 rows
```

Comment: @dran, there's a small error in there with the ranking of the segments, so I'll just correct that in a moment. Update: now sorted.

Comment: you have an IIF function call which should be replaced by a CASE expression, because IIF appeared in SQL Server 2012. Anyway, a very nice solution (especially if you wrote it without any testing)!

Comment: Good point @RazvanSocol. And yes, all written in Notepad++ without any access to a debugger.

Comment: @Steve, thank you!  I got the query and the report running using your approach since we are using 2008 server but will be transitioning to 2012 or higher I think this March (I think).  I was out of the office for a few days and wasn't able to open this and reply to your post.  Again thank you Steve and Razvan Socol for your help I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
    Product VARCHAR(10),
    TheTime TIME
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Product, TheTime) VALUES
('Frion','1:00'),
('Frion','2:00'),
('Bulbs','3:00'),
('Bulbs','4:00'),
('Bulbs','5:00'),
('Frion','6:00'),
('Frion','7:00'),
('Bulbs','8:00'),
('Bulbs','9:00'),
('Bulbs','10:00'),
('Bulbs','11:00'),
('Bulbs','12:00'),
('Frion','13:00'),
('Frion','14:00'),
('Bulbs','15:00'),
('Frion','16:00'),
('Bulbs','17:00'),
('Frion','18:00'),
('Frion','19:00'),
('Frion','20:00'),
('Frion','21:00'),
('Frion','22:00'),
('Bulbs','23:00')

;WITH X AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(Y.Dif) OVER (ORDER BY Y.TheTime) AS Grp
    FROM (
        SELECT *, 
            CASE 
                WHEN Product<>LAG(Product) OVER (ORDER BY TheTime) 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
            END AS Dif
        FROM @Table1
    ) Y
)
SELECT X1.Product, X1.TheTime, 
    --X1.Dif, X1.Grp, Q2.Grp, Q2.Cnt, Q2.PrevCnt,
    CASE 
        WHEN X1.Product='Frion' AND Q2.PrevCnt>4 AND X1.Dif=1 
        THEN 'NOT' 
        ELSE 'OK' 
    END AS Status
FROM X X1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *, LAG(Q1.Cnt) OVER (ORDER BY Q1.Grp) AS PrevCnt
    FROM (
        SELECT X2.Grp, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM X X2 GROUP BY X2.Grp
    ) Q1
) Q2 ON Q2.Grp = X1.Grp
ORDER BY TheTime
```

First, in the `Y` subquery, we mark each row where the Product is different than the Product in previous rows (the `Dif` column). The CTE named `X` calculates a group number for each row, by counting the number of different rows that appear until that row (the `Grp` column).

Then in `Q1` we calculate the number of rows in each group (the `Cnt` column) and in `Q2` we compute the number of rows in the previous group (the `PrevCnt` column).

Finally, we have the CASE expression to provide the expected result.

Comment: Thank you Razvan, at first it didn't run but I downloaded a trial version of sql 2012 and it did run.  We are currently using 2008 version of sql and not sure when we will upgrade or if we will be, but thank you again for your help and it gave me a a starting point and now just need to find a solution or a way to have this solution for a 2008 version of sql.  Again thank you!

Comment: @dran, you can actually implement this far easier in terms of `ROW_NUMBER`, which is available in SQL 2008. I'll draft a solution and post shortly.

Comment: Thank you Steve, that'll be highly appreciated.